Can you destroy property to save your life?
The Talmud [Bava Kamma 60b] discusses destroying property to save your life:

There were stacks of barley belonging to Jews in which the Philistines were hiding, and [King David wanted to burn down the stacks to kill the Philistines and save his own life].  He raised the dilemma: What is [the law?] [Is it permitted] to save oneself [by destroying] somebody else’s property?
They sent [the following answer] to him: It is prohibited to save oneself by destroying somebody else’s property. But you are king [so you can do it].

But doesn't pikuach nefesh allow you to destroy property to save your life?

Apparently not. What exactly is the question? Why should pikuach nefesh allow it?

@DoubleAA -- Because destroying property is neither idolatry, nor adultery, nor murder.

It's also not eating pork. So what?

At this point, if you don't understand, I can't explain.

רש”י (1) סא, א ד”ה לשם שמים) כתב מפורשות “דאיכא איסורא [להציל עצמו בממון חברו] לאיניש בעלמא”, ומדבריו למד רבי יעקב אטלינגר כי הספק היה בדיני איסור והיתר, ופסקו הסנהדרין שיש איסור להציל עצמו בממון חברו. ואמנם הבנין ציון הביא בסימן קס”ז, את תמיהת המשנה למלך בספרו פרשת דרכים “איך יתכן דבמקום פיקוח נפש אסור להציל עצמו בממון חברו” – כמפורש בגמרא בסנהדרין (1) עד, א) ובכתובות (2) יט, א) “אין לך דבר העומד בפני פיקוח נפש אלא ע”ז ושפיכות דמים וגילוי עריות”.

@Sholom --  Yes, Tosafot and the Rosh interpret this passage as merely requiring payment if one was forced to damage property.  But the Gemara could have added that, but didn't.

Basically you're asking -- what was the Hava Amina. Another approach is that the risk calculus here was fairly small; "can I destroy property if it increases my chance of survival by 5%?" I forget where I'd heard that pshat ...

To clarify your question: you're asking, based on rashis understanding of the gemara, why did David think it would be prohibited to destroy the property, since there is another gemara which explicitly states that one must only give up their life when faced with committing murder, adultery, or idol worship. If this is what you mean, I suggest quoting the  gemara that talks about the "three big sins"

Also, note that there are other gemaras that state other aveiros which one should die, instead of committing. For example, embarrassing someone publicly. So this type of contradiction is not new
