Is the נִרְדָּף obligated to pay for the damage caused by his rescuer?
The Gemara (Sanhedrin 74a) says that if someone caused damage while attempting to rescue his friend, he should really be liable to pay for the damages, but we still exempt him, so as not to discourage people from rescuing others.
My question is: in such a case, would the person who was rescued need to pay instead, as the Tur writes (Choshen Mishpat 426:1) that in general one must pay for the expenses of the person who caused him to be saved, and in this case he was rescued through the item that was damaged, or would he also be exempt, being that Min Hadin the one who caused the damage should have been required to pay?

See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/145548/can-you-destroy-property-to-save-your-life

I'd have to learn the Sugya, but perhaps damages are not paid due to benefit or restitution, but rather due to the person's action. He didn't break it, it is a Grama, how could he be liable. Surely with the logic we should obligate the Rodef - we don't do that either for the same reason.

@msj121 I'm pretty sure we don't obligate the Rodef because he's chayiv misa, therefore Kim lei b'd'rabba minei

@Loani not mutually exclusive but the rodef is the chaser. The questioner was asking about the chased (nirdaf)

@msj121 I know, I was just replying to your statement that "surely with the logic we should obligated the Rodef - we don't do that either for the same reason" that isn't necessarily true. Whether the nirdaf is considered a grama or not, wouldn't have an affect on the reason the Rodef is pattur, because the Rodef has Kim lei b'd'rabba minei

@Loani Source please... If Sanhedrin 72a, there the rodef steals, it is part and parcel of the act of the rodef. I am not convinced at first blush, that a 3rd party's act which causes a loss, if could be transferred due to restitution, would due to a chivuy mitah be patur with kim lei. Kim lei affects acts liable to the rodef who is chayav mitah.... I think the answer is that restitution is not transferred to another party due to benefit.
